# Network stream and multiple connections

Tags: c#, tcp, xna, networkstream

I am programming a Tcp server for an XNA game that me and a friend are creating and I was wondering how you send to a specific client that is connected to the server using NetworkStream. For example, you can get the host's player position and send that to the server that will send that to the other connected client.

Comment: I was following a tutorial that explained TcpClient and NetworkStream only seems to have .Write(). I first learned socket servers and you could use .SendTo() to do that, but i'm not sure how with NetworkStream.

Comment: The server will need to have multiple NetworkStreams, one for each client. Assuming the number of clients is not fixed, that will mean you will need to code the server to allocate and deallocate them as needed.

Comment: @ekolis I realise this has been a long time since posting but what strategy would you use to allocate and unallocate clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to read up on a few things:

This should get you started:

1. [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx)
2. [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx)

Your server will need to have a `TcpListener`. Create a list of clients if you want to support multiple clients. You will get one `TcpClient` for every connected client. Read data from the `NetworkStream` on each of these clients. When you receive data on one of them, send it to the others.

You will need to define some sort of protocol, so you know when the message from the client is complete and you can send it ahead.

Comment: You can define your own protocol, sure. But there's also another option: use an existing protocol, like those from WCF, or for example JSON-RPC.